# Matrix falling effect

Tags: optimization, c

How can I make this matrix effect more like the matrix movie?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
srand((unsigned) time(0));
int i,j;
system("color 0a");

while(1)
{
    i = rand() % 2;
    j= rand() % 2;
    if(j)
    {
       printf("%d ", i);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" %d", i);
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: matrix]

Of course it is better if it was moving but that's all what I can show.

Also it takes a notable time to compile, is there anything wrong I'm doing?

Comment: How is it not like the movie... what are you trying to do?

Comment: nb - a google search of "matrix animation javascript" will turn up a number of good examples in javascript.  The key is to index the display to place the character at a given x, y to achieve the "rain" effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What You Have Now:

You code is simple and concise. That in and of itself can be a desirable quality. I think we can make the code a little bit more concise while gaining some runtime efficiency.

Some changes I would make:

**Change** `srand((unsigned) time(0));` *to* `srand(time(NULL));`

- While both are correct, this is how I have seen seeds set more often, hence it is the idiomatic approach

**Change** `return 0` *to* `return EXIT_SUCCESS`

- Exit codes are included in `stdlib`, since you already using that library, you should also use the provided exit codes.

**Change** `rand()%2` *to* `rand()&1`

- The [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`) can be very inefficient on some architectures. Since you are only using `rand()` to get binary values, we can much more efficiently use the bitwise and operator (`&`) to get a 1 if the number is odd and a 0 if the number is even.

**Change** your while loop to remove intermediate variables:

```
while(1) {
 if(rand() & 1)
   printf("%d ", rand() & 1);
 else
   printf(" %d", rand() & 1);
}
```

All together I think you could simplify your code to this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
system("color 0a");

while(1) {
  if(rand() & 1)
    printf("%d ", rand() & 1);
  else
    printf(" %d", rand() & 1);
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is a pretty small and eloquent code for generating a matrix style output. If your happy with this you can stop right here.

---

However, it should be pointed out that [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) is a little heavy handed for just printing spaces, ones, and zeros. You could utilize [`putchar`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar) which will, unsurprisingly, put a character to `STDOUT`.

```
while(1) {
  if(rand() & 1) {
    putchar(48 + (rand()&1))
    putchar(' ');
  }
  else {
    putchar(' ')
    putchar(48 + (rand()&1));
  }
}
```

Note that now we have a [Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) **48** in out code, that is no good! Let's let the preprocessor help us make the code a little bit more readable:

```
#define ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET 48
while(1) {
  if(rand() & 1) {
    putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand()&1));
    putchar(' ');
  }
  else {
    putchar(' ');
    putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand()&1));
  }
}
```

Next is a matter of personal preference. I personally don't like 2 line `if` statements. If the `if` statement has 3 lines, it should probably be abstracted into a separate method, if it has one line, that’s perfect, but if we have 2 lines... that's murky water.

We could use the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) to clean up the line a little:

```
#define ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET 48
while(1) {
  if(rand() & 1)
    putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand()&2)), putchar(' ');
  else
    putchar(' '), putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand()&1));
}
```

Using the comma operator is a matter of preference. I think that there are times that it is perfectly clear & reasonable to use it, others say the comma operator should never be used because it is too opaque. While that code is more compact, I don't think it helps readability or efficiency.

Lets try abstraction that into a method instead and see how that looks:

```
while(1) {
  if(rand() & 1)
    printLeft();
  else
    printRight();
}
.
.
.
#define ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET 48
void printLeft() {
   putchar(' ');
   putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand()&1));
}

void printRight() {
   putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand()&1));
   putchar(' ');
}
```

That makes the while loop look better but the methods *might* incur some performance cost. Since your tag `Optimization` implies that you care most about runtime efficiency and not readability/maintainability lets try something else.

You will notice in your all the code examples above, there is some repetition in the while loop. In all the cases we have 2 statements printing the one or zero. Repetition is often a good thing to focus on because it can alert you to things that can be improved. There is a mantra of [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (DRY) in programming which is designed to help programmers locate inefficiencies and refactor their code for better readability & efficency.

Consider this loop:

```
int b;
while(1) {
  if(b = rand() & 1)
    putchar(' ');
  putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand() & 1));
  if(!b)
    putchar(' ');
}
```

Here we have a single binary number printing statement but conditionally print a space before or after the number. From a runtime efficiency perspective this is probably optimal (though I have not done any benchmarking).

If we put this all together we have the following:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET 48

int main() {
int b;
srand(time(NULL));
system("color 0a");

while(1) {
  if(b = (rand() & 1))
    putchar(' ');
  putchar(ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET + (rand() & 1));
  if(!b)
    putchar(' ');
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I hope this has given you a lot of different angles to view you code from and given you the tools to decide what you value when improving this code, readability or runtime efficiency.

Comment: good call, I forgot about that...

Comment: "Change `return 0` to `return EXIT_SUCCESS`" - Just get rid of the return completely, thanks to C99 & C11 §5.1.2.2(3); your parameters should be declared as `void`, if you don't take anything in (for example: `main(void)`); you should always initialize your variable on creation; and if you only have one statement in a test conditional, you should mimic [this style](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/16530/94014) to prevent bugs.

Comment: Also, you should make a note to *not* use `system()`, and instead use [ANSI escape codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219393/stdlib-and-colored-output-in-c).  All modern terminals implement them, and they will speed up the code.  And you forgot to `#include <time.h>` when you used `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking optimization (not sure you are) then one clear change is to remove printf -- printf is very slow.  You are only displaying `0`, `1`, and .

putc is much faster -- it does not have to parse for formatting.  If you change the code to use putc instead of printf you should see a dramatic speed boost.

Comment: You're wrong. I mean, there is no need to turn `print` into `putchar`. Indeed, the compiler will do that automatically if needed, even with no optimization flag turned on.
Checked on gcc.

Comment: @no1 - The `printf` (not `print`) optimization only happens for string literals,  `%s` and `%c`.  None of which is true for this example which is a `%d`.  This is why awashburn's answer requires the `ASCII_NUMBER_OFFSET` define. I'm not wrong, you are.  More info: http://www.ciselant.de/projects/gcc_printf/gcc_printf.html

Comment: There is no need to use that ugly macro, since you can directly 1) convert to char 2) add 0x30 - '0'.
Hence, either you call `printf("%c", n)` or `putchar(n + 0x30)` will be equivalent. Good to point out, though.